# Get top 5 largest from list of tuples - Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of tuples like this (generated from a select statement with sqlite3):

```
itemsAndQtyBought = [('Item no.1', 3), ('Item no.2', 0), ('Item no.3', 3), ('Item no.4', 2), ('Item no.5', 1), ('Item no.6', 9), ('Item no.7', 7)]
```

And the list carries on. It's a list of tuples and its got a product name and the quantity bought of that item.

I need to create anoter list of tuples of the top 5 items from that list of tuples with 5 of the items with the highest quantity bought.

For example with the list above it would turn out like this:

```
newItemsQtyBought = [('Item no.6', 9), ('Item no.7', 7), ('Item no.3', 3), ('Item no.1', 3), ('Item no.4', 2)]
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Why don't you just use the select statement itself to create the list of items you actually want?

Comment: Is it possible an item will be listed more than once?  In other words, is `[('apples', 3), ('apples', 2)]` supposed to add up to `('apples', 5)`?  If so, [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) does exactly what you want.  Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 13):

Just use sorted and slice the first 5 items:

```
In [170]: sorted(itemsAndQtyBought, key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)[:5]
Out[170]:
[('Item no.6', 9),
 ('Item no.7', 7),
 ('Item no.1', 3),
 ('Item no.3', 3),
 ('Item no.4', 2)]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`heapq.nlargest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import itemgetter

nlargest(5, my_list, key=itemgetter(1))
```

> heapq.nlargest(n, iterable[, key])
>
> Return a list with the *n* largest elements from the dataset defined by
>   iterable. *key*, if provided, specifies a function of one argument that
>   is used to extract a comparison key from each element in the iterable:
>   `key=str.lower` Equivalent to: `sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=True)[:n]`

**Output:**

```
>>> my_list = [('Item no.1', 3), ('Item no.2', 0),
...            ('Item no.3', 3), ('Item no.4', 2),
...            ('Item no.5', 1), ('Item no.6', 9),
...            ('Item no.7', 7)]
>>>
>>> nlargest(5, my_list, key=itemgetter(1))
[('Item no.6', 9), ('Item no.7', 7), ('Item no.1', 3), ('Item no.3', 3), ('Item no.4', 2)]
```

Comment: You beat me to it.I deleted my answer, but I would use `operator.itemgetter` instead of a lambda for the key!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Edited to use `operator.itemgetter()` instead of `lambda` ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
sorted(itemsAndQtyBought, key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)[:5]
```

Output:

```
[('Item no.6', 9), ('Item no.7', 7), ('Item no.1', 3), ('Item no.3', 3), ('Item no.4', 2)]
```

Only drawback: It sorts the whole list

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you

```
from operator import itemgetter

def newItem(oldItem):
        newItemQtyBought = sorted(oldItem,key=itemgetter(1))
        return newItemQtyBought[-5:]

def main():
        itemsAndQtyBought = [('Item no.1', 3), ('Item no.2', 0), ('Item no.3', 3), ('Item no.4', 2), ('Item no.5', 1), ('Item no.6', 9), ('Item no.7', 7)]
        print(newItem(itemsAndQtyBought))

if __name__=="__main__":
        main()
```